# I can't do WriteProcessMemory in python, so why?

Tags: python, ctypes, readprocessmemory

I write some code based in stackoverflow code's just to readmemory and compare with a single value. When true i need to replace this value for 0 or another value. But my writeprocessmemory isn't working, and i don't know why.
The output value for result is 1 - that means it's working
but the outbut value for result2 is 0 - means that isn't working

```
import ctypes as c
from ctypes import wintypes as w
import winsound
import time

pid = 7740 
Ids_pointer = [0x016E3E60, 0x015E47E0, 0x013E4A90, 0x011E4AB8, 0x016E4AB0, 0x014E4B08, 0x012B40C0]
k32 = c.windll.kernel32
OpenProcess = k32.OpenProcess
OpenProcess.argtypes = [w.DWORD,w.BOOL,w.DWORD]
OpenProcess.restype = w.HANDLE

ReadProcessMemory = k32.ReadProcessMemory
ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = [w.HANDLE,w.LPCVOID,w.LPVOID,c.c_size_t,c.POINTER(c.c_size_t)]
ReadProcessMemory.restype = w.BOOL


WriteMemory = k32.WriteProcessMemory
WriteMemory.argtypes = [w.HANDLE,w.LPCVOID,w.LPVOID,c.c_size_t,c.POINTER(c.c_size_t)]
WriteMemory.restype = w.BOOL

GetLastError = k32.GetLastError
GetLastError.argtypes = None
GetLastError.restype = w.DWORD

CloseHandle = k32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.argtypes = [w.HANDLE]
CloseHandle.restype = w.BOOL
e = GetLastError()


processHandle = OpenProcess(0x0010, False, pid)
processHandle2 = OpenProcess(0x0020, False, pid)


while 1:
    for q in range (0,7):
        data = c.c_ulong()
        bytesRead = c.c_ulonglong()
        result = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, Ids_pointer[q], c.byref(data), c.sizeof(data), c.byref(bytesRead))
        cmd = data.value
        print(cmd)
        print('result: {}, err code: {}, bytesRead: {}'.format(result, e, bytesRead.value))

        if cmd == 1919902817:
            for i in range (0,7):
                result2 = WriteMemory(processHandle2, Ids_pointer[i], c.byref(data), c.sizeof(data), None)
                print('result: {}, err code: {}, bytesRead: {}'.format(result2, e, bytesRead.value))

CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a useful description. What are you expecting, what's happening instead?

Comment: I expecting to modify memory value for every ids_pointer adress.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question. I forgot to add a "PROCESS_VM_OPERATION" to code. I simple add to processHandle2 and fixed the code.

processHandle2 = OpenProcess(0x0020 | 0x0008, False, pid)